# how to store an image in sql and retrieve it back?

Tags: vb.net

I have a picturebox from which the image will be stored and the name of the image will also be stored(it is for the reference of the image). then based on the name of the image given by the  textbox, the image should be displayed.

but in sql the image path is only stored how to store the image as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in sql the type of image is image.
now follow the below code

```
        cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO image VALUES(@name,@photo)", conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
        PictureBox1.BackgroundImage.Save(ms, PictureBox1.BackgroundImage.RawFormat)
        Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
        Dim p As New SqlParameter("@photo", SqlDbType.Image)
        p.Value = data
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```